# How to send multiple parameters in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

How to send parameters in `json` format?

**Below are my input parameters :**

```
[
    {
        "LoginID":151,
        "UserID":0,
        "SubUserID":0,
        "WorkGroupID":92,
        "WorksFor":"Doctor",
        "UserWorkGroup":0
    },
    {
        "SortingName":"",
        "Searching":true,
        "SortingOrder":"Desc",
        "RecordsCount":10,
        "PageIndex":0
    }
]
```

**Previously I was sending parameters as below :**

```
[getProfileServices sendSynchronousPostRequestWithStringForAction:getProfileURL andParameters:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"55",@"LoginID",@"0",@"UserID",@"0",@"SubUserID",@"90",@"WorkGroupID",@"Doctor",@"WorksFor",@"0",@"UserWorkGroup",nil] andRequestType:@"POST"];
```

how to sent like this but now i need to add some more input mentioned above ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use following code..

```
NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableDictionary * myData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[myData setValue:@"151" forKey:@"LoginID"];
[myData setValue:@"0" forKey:@"UserID"];
[myData setValue:@"0" forKey:@"SubUserID"];
[myData setValue:@"92" forKey:@"WorkGroupID"];
[myData setValue:@"Doctor" forKey:@"WorksFor"];
[myData setValue:@"0" forKey:@"UserWorkGroup"];

[myArray addObject:myData];

myData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[myData setValue:@"," forKey:@"SortingName"];
[myData setValue:@"1" forKey:@"Searching"];
[myData setValue:@"Desc" forKey:@"SortingOrder"];
[myData setValue:@"10" forKey:@"RecordsCount"];
[myData setValue:@"0" forKey:@"PageIndex"];
[myArray addObject:myData];

NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Your final jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);
```

If you want to send this data to Server, then you can use this code:

```
NSData *dataToSend = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:0 error:nil];

[getProfileServices sendSynchronousPostRequestWithStringForAction:getProfileURL andParameters:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dataToSend] andRequestType:@"POST"];
```

Comment: excellent but how to add that dictionary in this post request                                                                                                [getProfileServices sendSynchronousPostRequestWithStringForAction:getProfileURL andParameters:[ ,nil] andRequestType:@"POST"];

Comment: At the end, you will get a NSString. So you can send this data as a string. I think, you have already sent a string on server before. So you can use same code here.

Comment: ya i got string but how to send it in post request ?

Comment: Check my updated answer for this. I have write a solution to send a array on server. but if you have a solution to send a string to server, then you can able to use that.

Comment: i used same code but getting error    no visible @interface for NSDictionary declares the selector 'initwithObjectsAndKeys and request type

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"LoginID":@"151",@"UserID":@"0",@"SubUserID":@"0",@"WorkGroupID":@"92",@"WorksFor":@"Doctor",@"UserWorkGroup":@"0"};

NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"SortingName":@",",@"Searching":@"true",@"SortingOrder":@"Desc",@"RecordsCount":@"10",@"PageIndex":@"0"};


NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict1,dict2, nil];

NSData *dataToSend = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:0 error:nil];

[getProfileServices sendSynchronousPostRequestWithStringForAction:getProfileURL andParameters:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dataToSend andRequestType:@"POST"];
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

add it in `NSMutableArray` and add that array to `NSDictionary`. like;

```
{"LoginID":151,"UserID":0,"SubUserID":0,"WorkGroupID":92,"WorksFor":"Doctor","UserWorkGroup":0}
```

this goes in `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableArray` goes to `NSDictionary`

Comment: yaaa thats ok but how to add sorting array in dictionary

Comment: [dict setObject: your array forKey: key];

Comment: not able add please please can you format it sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to put **array** into the **dictionary** is

```
  @{@[element],@[element],@[element]}
```

Comment: This is absolutely unrelated answer.